# Minify at the web server level or at CDN level?

Tags: performance, cdn

I run a Buddypress community-based website (Wordpress) and currently my site speed score is E. I am planning to buy WP Rocket because I really want to make my site faster.

I use the following services:

- Bunny CDN
- Cloudflare

Caching has never been my forte (last I tried broke my website) so my question is. How do I combine those things to make my website super fast and which is faster? minify at the webserver level or at CDN level?

Comment: Much more info is needed to guess what the best area to target might be, including your hosting solution, apart from the narrow question of where to minify.

Answer (score 2):

It is best to do minification server side for a few different reasons

1. Future proofs in the event you change CDNs.  Minification will always be on your side and you won't need to worry about that feature if you change CDNs.
2. Ease of troubleshooting.  If there are any issues with the minification you  can control it on the server without having to involved CDN support.
3. CDNs are designed, and architected, to deliver content, not necessarily optimize the content.

Also, I'd recommend only a single CDN provider.  Multiple CDNs can over complicate things.  Look at CloudFlare and their RocketLoader product.  I'm not sure about price, though could be useful.

Comment: Hi, you said "Also, I'd recommend only a single CDN provider. Multiple CDNs can over complicate things. Look at CloudFlare and their RocketLoader product. I'm not sure about price, though could be useful."

Are you suggesting not to use Cloudflare when using BunnyCDN? I'm using Cloudflare pure for DNS and to hide the IP of the server. Bunny is used pure for CDN and video streaming.